# Python OpenOPC error item definition doesn't conform to the server's syntax 0xC0040008

Tags: python, opc

I'm evaluating OpenOPC to create a client to talk to DeltaV OPC server. I've have a Matrikon OPC Server Simulator running. When I list properties for that simulator server I am able to see the properties like

```
pranny@Sandbox2 MINGW64 ~
$ opc -p Random.Int4
Random.Int4     0     Item ID (virtual property)     Random.Int4
Random.Int4     1     Item Canonical DataType        VT_I4
Random.Int4     2     Item Value                     14240
Random.Int4     3     Item Quality                   Good
Random.Int4     4     Item Timestamp                 04/05/17 07:48:20
Random.Int4     5     Item Access Rights             Read
Random.Int4     6     Server Scan Rate               100.0000
Random.Int4     7     Item EU Type                   0
Random.Int4     8     Item EUInfo                    None
Random.Int4     101   Item Description               Random value.
```

But when I connect to the DeltaV OPC Server server, I get error like

```
pranny@Sandbox2 MINGW64 ~
$ opc -p ANALOG_1/AI1/SIMULATE_IN.CV

properties: The item definition does not conform to the server's syntax. (OLE error 0xc0040008)
```

I did a little bit of research and found these common causes. However, I verified and none of them worked in my case

- [Custom Tag Structure](https://www.opcsupport.com/link/portal/4164/4590/Article/568/If-I-am-using-the-proper-Syntax-why-won-t-the-tag-validate) The tag structure shown by Matrikon OPC Explorer shows the same properties like Canonical data type, value, quality etc.
- [Permissions Error](https://www.opcsupport.com/link/portal/4164/4590/Article/2670/I-am-connecting-to-the-DeltaV-OPC-Server-using-MatirkonOPC-Tunneller-but-my-tags-won-t-validate-why) Even if the login was DeltaV Administrator, it reported the same error

At this time I am also considering using something like an OPC Tunneller from matrikon, but OpenOPC is doing the same thing essentially, so not sure if tunneller would also help.

Comment: The error comes from the server and it's telling you that ANALOG_1/AI1/SIMULATE_IN.CV is not how the item IDs for that server should look like. Use some OPC client with item browsing capability (e.g. Matrikon OPC Explorer) to find the true Item ID for that item. I do not remember the UI of it precisely, but it should display the item ID when you click on a node in the address space tree, or a bit later somewhere.

Comment: In the OPC Explorer I am able to browse the tags correctly. After some fiddling I managed to get the `opc -p ANALOG_1/AI1/SIMULATE_IN.CV` to work correctly. But now I have a python implementation that throws the same error. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Try using both the **name of the file** and **tag names** in ***lowercase***